# Why does autologin into hats not work?

Tags: bug, login, winter-bash-2016

I join http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/ at work. But when I get to the computer at home and click [the link](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/) I am not autologin in comparison to any other Stack Overflow-type site I was joined.

This requires me to click http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/auth/login to log in.

Why does auto log in into Winter Bash not work?

Comment: If your work and home are different computers, I'm pretty sure on your home box the cookie for the winterbash2016 site wasn't there yet.

Comment: I am logged in on SO and expects autologin on other sites. In this case `winter bash`

Comment: You still need the auth cookie for the domain, you need to pass through an authentication step, at least once.

Comment: I had gone onto stack, saw I was logged in. Then, I clicked the winterbash site and it wasn't logged in. something is up.